# Keep last checkbox checked after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have 6 checkboxes, and I need the last one that gets checked, to stay checked after a page refresh.

What I have now is keeping all the checked checkboxes, checked after page refresh.

Any ideas on how do I edit it to achieve the needed result?

Here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Persist checkboxes 1</title>
  </head>

  <body>

      <input type="checkbox" id="option1">

      <input type="checkbox" id="option2">

      <input type="checkbox" id="option3">

      <input type="checkbox" id="option4">

      <input type="checkbox" id="option5">

      <input type="checkbox" id="option6">


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
        var checkboxValues = {};
        $(":checkbox").each(function(){
          checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
        });
        $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 1, path: '/' })
      });

      function repopulateCheckboxes(){
        var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
        if(checkboxValues){
          Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
            var checked = checkboxValues[element];
            $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
          });
        }
      }

      $.cookie.json = true;
      repopulateCheckboxes();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So if a user selects 3 checkboxes, you just want whatever the *last* checkbox was they selected to be persisted after refresh, correct?

Comment: @jeffdill2 Yes, correct.

Comment: refreshed how?  By clicking a page control or the browser refresh button

Comment: Is the code you have here currently working at all? I ask because you're targeting an `#option` id for your `change` event, but none of your `input` elements would match that selector because they're all `#option1`, `#option2`, etc.

Comment: why not $('input').last().prop('checked', checked); ?:)

Comment: @jeffdill2 yes it does, I know that it's targeting something else, but it does. I'll edit it to a little more clear.

Comment: @Bindrid refresh page or going to another page

Comment: @SkyWookie that wouldn't work if they selected the checkbox at the bottom  first, and *then* selected the checkbox at the top.

Comment: @DeneaNovac did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only wanting to persist the last checkbox that's selected, instead of iterating over all of your checkboxes and storing them in the cookie, just overwrite the cookie each time a checkbox is selected with the `id` of whatever was selected, and then you'll always have the most recent `id` persisted in your cookie:

```
<script>
  $("[id^=option]").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) { // This will make sure an ID isn't stored if a checkbox is unchecked.
      $.cookie('checkboxId', this.id, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
    }
  });

  function repopulateCheckboxes() {
    var checkboxId = $.cookie('checkboxId');

    if (checkboxId) {
      $("#" + checkboxId).prop('checked', checked);
    }
  }

  $.cookie.json = true;
  repopulateCheckboxes();
</script>
```